# Validation error of type FieldUndefined in Amplify.GraphQLError and AppSyncRealTimeClient

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-ios, appsync-subscription

I'm trying to use Amplify for the backend in my Swift app and get no errors when configuring Amplify and saving new Users into the DataStore or images into S3 Store but get a mistake with AWSAPIPlugin when trying to upload everything to the cloud via AppSync. Here is how the errors look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fDVL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ia5C.png)

I was trying to have everything in my swift code sync with amplify but it doesn't connect and upload anything